# Butterfly animation on Imageview Android

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-animation, android-view

I would like to take an Imageview that has a butterfly png and animate it so it looks like the butterfly is moving its wings.

How can I get this effect with an Android native animation ?

[image]

Comment: Did you tired anything?

Comment: I tried creating a kindda flip animation, but its not good, maybe trying to look for a Lib that can help.

Comment: I wuold use a gif. Can't you use a gif?

Comment: Cant use gif :/

Comment: Assuming that you want folding wings without moving across the screen, I still think your options are either (1) cut image into 2 wings and 1 body; save space by just flipping one wing; so you'll have 3 imageviews, and doing some type of flip-like animation OR (2) manually create a set of images with wing flapping and show that similar to gif

Comment: Thanks Morrison im testing something now, if thats not it I will work the way you tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done that in iOS, so you need to scale it up and scale it down with a timer.

Answer (score 2):

It worked, this is what I did, First I used Glide to load my img, then I created an animation like so:

```
final ScaleAnimation growanim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, randscale), 1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
        growanim.setDuration(randomDuration);
        growanim.setRepeatCount(-1);
        growanim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        growanim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        img.setAnimation(growanim);
        growanim.start();
```

randomDuration = random.nextInt(2000 - 100 + 1) + 100l); --> random times.
randscale = random.nextFloat()*0.5f)+0.3f);---> random scales.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)  Simple Example:

```
ImageView iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
if (iView != null)
Glide.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/1ALnB2s.gif").asGif().into(iView);
```

Detailed Example

```
// For a simple view:
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  Glide.with(this).load("http://some image link").into(imageView);
}

// For a simple image list:
@Override public View getView(int position, View recycled, ViewGroup container) {
  final ImageView myImageView;
  if (recycled == null) {
    myImageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_image_view, container, false);
  } else {
    myImageView = (ImageView) recycled;
  }

  String url = myUrls.get(position);

  Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);

  return myImageView;
}
```

Output:

[image]

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

[Wiki Link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, unfortunately I cannot use gifs.