# Android - Fit gif to screen sizes

Tags: android, imageview, gif

I am using [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) library to show gif image in my android application. As you know gif images should be in `assets` folder not in `drawable`, so android can not switch between different sizes automatically.

How can I handle this for different screen sizes?

Comment: Can check for [Screen width and height programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18712361/2870496) and load different gif as the screen size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Butterfly animation on Imageview Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976690/butterfly-animation-on-imageview-android)

Comment: @MaňishYadav this question is completely different, why do you mark it as duplicate? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one way:

Try to Change gifs manually. Use `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;` to find device density and then change gif based on this.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323437/6005977) Find Device density of device and set gif-image accordingly. More idea about [DisplayMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)