# Loading images in recyclerview with picasso from api

Tags: android, picasso

Add image in RecyclerView from api using picasso

Comment: Add your code, you did so far and we will guide you.

Comment: tell me what you have tried and we can guide you from there.

Comment: Step 1 : Google it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load Image from Picaso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976690/butterfly-animation-on-imageview-android)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Image loading using Picasso is very easy, you can do it like this way `Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);` and in their [website](http://square.github.io/picasso/) you can get every details. In your case you can parse every image URL and use `RecyclerView` to show them along with Picasso.

Answer (score 13):

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView)
```

In the new versions of Picasso you don't need the context anymore.
I'm using:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Answer (score 7):

**In the new versions of Picasso used `get()`**
Picasso latest version Picasso library: **2.71828**

```
Picasso
.get()
.load("You Img Path Place Here")
.resize(width, height)
.noFade()
.into("Path set ImageView");
```

Used latest picasso version

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Comment: As per new dependency it is the correct implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
String img_url = "YOUR IMAGE URL";
    if (!img_url.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        Picasso.with(context).load(img_url).placeholder(R.drawable.user_image)// Place holder image from drawable folder
       .error(R.drawable.user_image).resize(110, 110).centerCrop()
       .into("IMAGE VIEW ID WHERE YOU WANT TO SET IMAGE");
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can load image using picasso like this way

```
Picasso.with(context).load(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);
```

https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/image-loading-recyclerview-picasso.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all you use latest picasso version

1: `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`
2:  Now you can use use code in your recyclerview.

```
 Picasso.get()
                .load( cartfetchlist.get(position).ProductImages)
                .fit()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.fruits)
                .into(holder.product_image);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here ctx is context, `list.getImage_full_path())` is image coming from server, in placeholder a static image is placed if image is not loaded, on error kent is name of image and `into(servicecart_image)` is placed in XML so image is loaded there

```
 Picasso.with(ctx).load(list.getImage_full_path()).resize(160, 200).placeholder(R.drawable.kent)
                .error(R.drawable.kent).into(servicecart_image);
```